# Python 3.6: Floor division of a complex number

Tags: python, division, complex-numbers, python-3.6, floor-division

I need to floor divide a complex number, but it appears that floor division by complex numbers was removed in Python 3.x.

Is there any workarounds for this?  Any ideas would be appreciated.

eg.

```
(2 + 3i) // (complex anything) will throw an error.
```

Comment: Give us a value for `(anything)`? Unless it is a multiple of `(2+3j)`, then your answer will also be complex, hence floor-division is not well-defined. You can implement division by multiplying by `(anything).conjugate / (abs(anything)**2)`

Comment: Can I ask exactly what do you mean by floor division for complex numbers? I suppose that there is something I am missing, but there is no obvious way of defining it as far as I can tell

Comment: Thank for your comments.  I found a library (mpmath) with the necessarily tools.

Comment: @ smci -- Sorry, I actually meant "complex" anything.  I edited the question to make it clear.  That seems quite a clever workaround, however.

Comment: @MiKo -- it can be done, just tricky I think.  Python 2.x used to have the functionality.

Comment: @Engine I do not doubt it can be done, but since there is no "standard" way of sorting complex numbers how you define it matters a lot, I am just curious at what does it mean: what is the floor of (2.3 +3.5j), for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the mpmath library.  It has large amount of tools, including floor and mod for complex numbers. It appears that its actually included with SymPy.

Answer (score 3):

Complex numbers in python 3 are defined with their imaginary part as `j`, not `i`.

You are right that in Python 3 you can't compute floor division of complex numbers anymore, but you need to specify how you want it to behave, if you need a workaround.

In any case, you will need to implement a new class that inherits from `complex`, and override the `__floordiv__` method

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I just found a library that will work.

Answer (score 1):

Unless `(anything)` is a multiple of `(2+3j)`, then your answer will also be complex, hence floor-division is not well-defined. You can implement division by multiplying by `(anything).conjugate / (abs(anything)**2)`